# Splitting parameters in a macro

Tags: macros, strings, xstring

I have a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\listanimals}[1]{
    Animals in the farm: #1.
}
```

So using `\listanimals{pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat}` will print:

> Animals in the farm: pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat.

I want to know, can I have other macros display only certain information within that parameter?

For example:

```
\listfirsttwoanimals{pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat}
```

> First two animals: pig / sheep.

```
\listanimalsafterfirsttwo{pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat}
```

> Animals after the first two: cow / duck / goat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\listfirsttwoanimals[1]{First two animals:
  \StrBefore[2]{#1}{/}}
\newcommand\listanimalsafterfirsttwo[1]{Animals after first two:
  \StrBehind[2]{#1}{/}} 
\begin{document}     
\listfirsttwoanimals{pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat}

\listanimalsafterfirsttwo{pig / sheep / cow / duck / goat}
\end{document}
```

This assumes that the agrument always has more than two animals, so, for example,`\listfirsttwoanimals{pig / sheep }` returns no animals, while  `\listfirsttwoanimals{pig / sheep /}` gives pig and sheep.  `xstring` has functions like `\IfSubStr` which may be used to test this and return, for example, "I have only N animals" if N<3.